# Android : how to keep data as configurable

Tags: android, configurable

In my application for every launch, i want to sync data in my DB only if the last sync had happened before "x" hours. I want this parameter as configurable. Like it should be possible to set as 24 hours and later change whenever needed.

Where can i keep this parameter ? or what is the right way of handling this requirement.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html